# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62 cannot be cast to org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-search

I'm having an issue with Spring and Hibernate Search.  Here is my code:

```
@Slf4j
@Repository
public class DefaultIndexBuilderDao implements IndexBuilderDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void rebuildIndex() {
        try {
            log.debug("Starting the reindex process...");
            FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(getEntityManager());
            fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
            log.debug("Reindex complete.");
        } catch( InterruptedException e ) {
            log.warn("Error rebuilding index: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62 cannot be cast to org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor
    at org.hibernate.search.impl.FullTextSessionImpl.<init>(FullTextSessionImpl.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.search.impl.ImplementationFactory.createFullTextSession(ImplementationFactory.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.search.Search.getFullTextSession(Search.java:45)
    at com.domainwww.dao.DefaultIndexBuilderDao.rebuildIndex(DefaultIndexBuilderDao.java:38)
    at com.domainwww.service.DefaultIndexBuilderService.rebuildIndex(DefaultIndexBuilderService.java:30)
    at com.domainwww.beans.admin.IndexBean.reindex(IndexBean.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:107)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 57 more
```

Here are the versions from my POM (properties) (in case this is a version conflict)

```
<spring.version>5.3.1</spring.version>
<hibernate.version>5.4.24.Final</hibernate.version>
<hibernate.search.version>5.11.7.Final</hibernate.search.version>
```

Here is by bean for entityManager:

```
<bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="net.xxxx,com.xxxx.dbmanager3.settings" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect.storage_engine">innodb</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">filesystem</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">/opt/xxx/lucene/indexes</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

So I get that Spring is injecting a Proxy, so how should I be obtaining the FullTextEntityManager, unwrapping seems to leave me with the same error? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is typically what happens when using Hibernate Search `5.11.5.Final` and below with Spring boot 2.4 / Spring 5.3. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26090

Given the `ClassCastException` occurs at `FullTextSessionImpl.java:62`, I suspect you are not actually using Hibernate Search `5.11.7.Final`: in Hibernate Search `5.11.7.Final`, this line is just an `instanceof` test. In `5.11.5.Final` and below, this line actually is a cast.

I see you set property `hibernate.search.version` to `5.11.7.Final`, but did you use this property anywhere in your POM? Spring Boot doesn't manage the dependency to Hibernate Search, so you need to specify the version yourself in your `<dependency>` markup.

Comment: You are correct, I checked build directory, but I missed a stale jar that was being added to the CP  and being used.